# Nesting @keyframe in @media

Tags: css, keyframe

I have to fix a bug with curly brackets. But all opening brackets have pair.
There are error on line 212

> Expected RBRACE at line 212, col 2.
>       @-webkit-keyframes move {

But when I test code separate before 212 and after 212 - no errors seen.

```
@media all and (min-width:  1px){
.main-pointing-slider .box .dot-4{
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 128px;
    top: auto;
    right: auto;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: calc(50% - 3px);
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation-name: dotShow;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: dotShow;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 2s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-name: dotShow;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #dcd4cb 0%, #f3c886 100%)
}
.main-pointing-slider .box .svg-gradient{
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute
}
.main-pointing-slider .box .svg-gradient .svg-box{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
.main-pointing-slider .box .svg-gradient .svg-box rect{
    visibility: visible
}
.main-pointing-slider .slide{
    /*display: none;*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    overflow: hidden
}
.main-pointing-slider .slide .point{
    top: 1px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 1px;
    position: relative;
    width: 248px;
    height: 126px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 120px;
    -moz-border-radius: 120px;
    border-radius: 120px;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0
    auto
}
.main-pointing-slider .slide .point .svg-gradient-point{
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2
}
.main-pointing-slider .slide .point .svg-gradient-point .svg-box{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
.main-pointing-slider .slide .point .svg-gradient-point .svg-box rect{
    stroke-width: 2
}
.main-pointing-slider .slide .point .point-inner{
    top: 0;
    right: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 120px;
    -moz-border-radius: 120px;
    border-radius: 120px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: no-repeat 50%;
    background-size: cover
}
.main-pointing-slider .slide .point-shadow{
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 260px;
    height: 130px;
    width: calc(260px - 6px);
    height: calc(130px - 6px);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 120px;
    -moz-border-radius: 120px;
    border-radius: 120px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    margin: 0
    auto;
    background: black
}
.main-pointing-slider .slide .upper-text{
    top: auto;
    right: -100%;
    bottom: 72%;
    left: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 62%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: "Tahoma Bold",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1.12;
    color: #e7c28b;
    display: none
}
.main-pointing-slider .slide .lower-text{
    top: 34%;
    right: -100%;
    bottom: auto;
    left: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 53%;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Tahoma Regular",sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.3;
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
    display: none
}
.main-pointing-slider .slide.active{
    display: block
}
.main-pointing-slider.startFirstFrame .line{
    -webkit-animation-name: move;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.9s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -moz-animation-name: move;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.9s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-name: move;
    animation-duration: 0.9s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-timing-function: ease
}
.slide.animationIn .point{
    -webkit-animation-name: point;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-animation-name: point;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-name: point;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards
}
.slide.animationIn .point-shadow{
    -webkit-animation-name: point;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-animation-name: point;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-name: point;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards
}
.slide.animationIn .upper-text{
    animation: slideLeft 0.5s 0.25s ease forwards, slideLeftFinish 0.25s 0.75s ease forwards;
}
.slide.animationIn .lower-text{
    animation: slideLeft 0.5s 0.5s ease forwards, slideLeftFinish 0.25s 1s ease forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.1);
        -moz-transform: scaleX(0.1);
        -ms-transform: scaleX(0.1);
        transform: scaleX(0.1);
        opacity: 1
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
        -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
        -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
        transform: scaleX(1);
        opacity: 1
    }

}
```

}

Because of this error, validator can't see a closet bracket in @media.

Comment: Looks like you need to remove your keyframe animation from the media query block, you shouldn't need to declare it there anyway - declare it outside of any media queries and use them when appropriate (within or without media queries).

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Thank you so much! Problem solved

Comment: Great! I've added an official answer with a link to the W3C specification where this issue is documented for reference sake and for anyone else who may come across your question and find themselves experiencing the same issue. And on that note; to *clearly outline the issue*, and make this more applicable and easier to find for anyone else experiencing this issue, would you mind if I update the title of your question to "**Nesting @keyframe in @media**"?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Thank you. Yes, I did it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the W3C specification:

> At-rules inside @media are invalid in CSS2.1.

ref: [www.w3.org - Media types](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#at-media-rule)

**So this won't work:**

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {

   @media (max-width: 450px) {

   }

}
```

**Neither will this:**

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {

   @-webkit-keyframes animation {

   }

}
```

Keyframe animations should be declared outside of any media types then applied within the applicable or relevant media quieres when and where necessary.